# How to remove Ammap map control overlay?

Tags: javascript, ammap

How can I remove the controls for panning and zooming when displaying my AmMap? Is there a field I can change when creating my map object or do I have to manually alter the library code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can disable the pan/zoom buttons using the `zoomControl` fields when creating the map:

```
mapObj = new AmCharts.AmMap()
mapObj.zoomControl = {
       zoomControlEnabled: false,
       panControlEnabled: false
};
```